# MySQL C++ Connector UPDATE

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I am having trouble with the MySQL C++ Connector... My problem is I have a query : `UPDATE characters SET name = 'myNameIs' WHERE characregistra = 'MyguidIs'`
characters is the table, name a column, characregistra too. I try to put the myNameIs value into name when I found in the column characregistra the value "MyguisIs". It works, but without try{]catch{], it crashes. I tried to get the error with a sql::SQLException, but no way, nothing in printed...
Thanks in advance.

EDIT : forgot to put the code :

```
void renameCharac(std::string guid, std::string pseudo)
{
    try{
        sql::Statement *declaration;
        declaration = connection->createStatement(); // Connection is declared
        declaration->executeQuery("UPDATE characters SET name = '" + pseudo + "' WHERE characregistra = '" + guid + "'");
        delete declaration;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using without the `delete declaration`.  I'm still not sure if the value returned by `createStatement()` can be `delete`d.

Comment: It can, and it doesn't change anything deleting or not (except the memory...) I am deleting every statements when I do any SELECT query, and still don't have any problem. It happens only with UPDATE (haven't tried with INSERT)

Comment: Try to catch that exception by reference - catch (sql::SQLException &e). The exception thrown may be a child of sql::SQLException, not the SQLException directly and that copying of that exception into SQLException may lose information.

Comment: I ever tried, but didn't work, MSVC Says : "First-chance exception at 0x7623C42D in NLServeur.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x0017FC68." when he is on the line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I did it like that :

```
void renameCharac(std::string guid, std::string pseudo)
{
        sql::Statement *declaration;
        declaration = connection->createStatement();
        declaration->executeUpdate("UPDATE characters SET name = '" + pseudoChoisi + "' WHERE characregistra = '" + guid + "'");
        delete declaration;
}
```

It works.